# Delete backwards from end of the line character

Tags: vim

I know this sounds very easy, but I couldn't find an elegant way to do it.

I have to retain the below line but remove `*/` from the end:

```
(This line is needed);*/
```

I pressed `g_` to move to the last character (i.e. `/`). Now how do I delete *only* the `*/` to get

```
(This line is needed);
```

I tried `dT*` and `db` — neither works as expected.

Comment: Please format the question to make it clear. `here is my requirement` - what is it?

Comment: You could use '$' instead of 'g_' to go to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

is this ok?

```
$xx

$ - to the end of line
xx - remove the last two chars
```

or if you have many other chars after last `*`:

```
$F*D
```

or use `:s` command if you have many lines to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Backwards motions (like [`b`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#b)) are [exclusive](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#exclusive), which is why the character under the cursor isn't getting deleted.  The canonical way to change the backwards delete to be inclusive is to use visual mode, e.g. `dvb` or `dvF*`.

Note that neither `dT*` nor `dvT*` will do what you want since that's is a `till` motion, which moves up till, but not including, the specified character.  `f`/`F` are the corresponding motions which include the character.